# Android Tag Manager container get null each time Application launches

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, singleton, google-tag-manager

This is how I get Tag Manager keys in my project. I am using singleton class, so it does not hit Tag Manager service again and again.

But when I closed and relaunch the application, it gets container null, and hit google tag manager service one time again.

I want it to have container data on application relaunch, so it won't hit server again for at least 12 hours (The default expiry time of container).

Kindly guide me.

```
public class ContainerHolderSingleton {

    private static ContainerHolder containerHolder;

    private ContainerHolderSingleton() {
    }

    public static ContainerHolder getContainerHolder() {
        return containerHolder;
    }

    public static void setContainerHolder(ContainerHolder c) {
        containerHolder = c;
    }

}
```

**TagManager**

```
public String initTagManager(){

        CONTAINER_ID= sampleApp.getAppContext().getResources().getString(R.string.tag_manager_id);

        TagManager tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext());

        if(ContainerHolderSingleton.getContainerHolder() == null) {

            PendingResult pending = tagManager.loadContainerPreferFresh(
                    CONTAINER_ID, 
                    R.raw.gtmnh6xdp);  


            ContainerHolder containerHolder = (ContainerHolder) pending.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
        }
        if (ContainerHolderSingleton.getContainerHolder().getStatus() != com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status.zzalw) {
            kURL = staticURL;
        }

        container = ContainerHolderSingleton.getContainerHolder().getContainer();
        if (ContainerHolderSingleton.getContainerHolder().getContainer() != null)
            kURL = container.getString(TMURLKey);


         if (kURL.isEmpty()) {

            kURL = staticURL;
        }

        return kURL;
    }
```

Comment: your title doesn't match with content.

Comment: @M.Ashish .Apologies, I have updated question title

Comment: I think for you should have store data locally. And every time your app launches, show the local data and in background update the tag data whenever you want.

Comment: What's the intent of comparing getStatus with a proguarded value?
why not use:
containerHolder.getStatus().isSuccess()